# Applying CSS on drawn Canvas Elements

Tags: css, angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive, css-animations

Is it possible to apply CSS Animations (in my case a glowing effect) to a circle that is drawn on a canvas by javascript?

I am using this angularjs directive: https://github.com/angular-directives/angular-round-progress-directive/blob/master/angular-round-progress-directive.js

I use it as a counter, and I want it to glow every second (got the css code for the animation already.

Is that possible? 
Another idea would be, to make the canvas itself circular, and apply the glowing effect to the canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't apply CSS to elements drawn in the canvas, because they don't exist on the DOM. It's just as if they were a bitmap image.

You could use an [SVG circle](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_circle.asp) though, which will allow you to [style the circle](http://www.sitepoint.com/svg-styling-with-css/) with CSS and use animations:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't apply CSS to shapes drawn to canvas, but you can create a glow effect simply by using the shadow.

**[A demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BdGQ/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), // canvas
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),              // context
    w = canvas.width,                           // cache some values
    h = canvas.height,
    cx = w * 0.5,
    cy = h * 0.5,
    glow = 0,                                   // size of glow
    dlt = 1,                                    // speed
    max = 40;                                   // max glow radius

ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(100, 100, 255, 1)';     // glow color
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';                         // circle color

function anim() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);                  // clear frame
    ctx.shadowBlur = glow;                      // set "glow" (shadow)

    ctx.beginPath();                            // draw circle
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, cx * 0.25, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.fill();                                 // fill and draw glow

    glow += dlt;                                // animate glow
    if (glow <= 0 || glow >= max) dlt = -dlt;

    requestAnimationFrame(anim);                // loop
}
anim();
```

[image: example]

**Update**

To get a outline with outer glow you can simply "punch out" the center of the circle using a composite operation. Here the example uses save/restore to remove the shadow - you can optimize the code by manually resetting these - but for simplicity, do the following modification:

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
// remove shadow from global

function anim() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // draw main circle and glow
    ctx.save();                                 // store current state
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(100, 100, 255, 1)';
    ctx.shadowBlur = glow;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, cx * 0.25, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.restore();                              //restore -> removes the shadow

    // draw inner circle
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; // removes what's being drawn
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, cx * 0.23, 0, 6.28);          // smaller filled circle
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; // reset

    glow += dlt;
    if (glow <= 0 || glow >= max) dlt = -dlt;

    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

The composite operation will remove the pixels from the next draw operation. Simply draw a smaller filled circle on top which will leave an outline of the first circle and its glow.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BdGQ/1/)**

[image: example2]

Comment: this is REALLY helpful! unfortunately, i can't apply it to my sample. Would you mind helping me out on this one? I only want to have the glowing effect on the outer circle - but all I can get is a glowing effect on all the circles - but without animation :( see my git here: https://github.com/manulitopetito/angular-progress

Comment: still trying (for 3 hours straight...) but no luck.. would it be better to draw the outer circle on a second canvas?

Comment: @user2556555 (late answer->timezone diff.) Sure, but could you set up a fiddle as I don't know your code. Just put in the essential part and I'll have a look. In essence: you can "stamp" out the center of the circle after drawing it using a composite mode (set globalCompositeOperation mode to destination-out and draw a smaller circle on top with shadow disabled, set back mode to source-over). See this mod: http://jsfiddle.net/4BdGQ/1/