# How to add css properties to canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I am using canvas in my html page.
Adding css properties directly to the drawn canvas is not possible,But How to add `css` property to `html5 canvas`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757825/applying-css-on-drawn-canvas-elements

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use some CSS like width and height via id or class.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

All other colors of objects you draw on it you have to define in your drawing script. Have a look in the documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS in Canvas like .

> ```
>  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
> ```

You can not add css properties on drawn canvas instead , you can use Javascript to add effects into it.

For More refer this SO [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757825/applying-css-on-drawn-canvas-elements)